# I cant sort the below type of json data. Is tihs json data is possible to sorting in descending order

Tags: arrays

var group = {"data":[{
"name": "user1",
"id": 3
}, {
"name": "user2",
"id": 6
}, {
"name": "user3",
"id": 1
}]};

Comment: Sort by what? Which programming language you are using? What attempt you made?

Comment: Have you tried parsing the JSON, doing the sort, and then loading (or stringifying, or whatever your language's process is) the data back into JSON?

Comment: @ Chetan Ranpariya  yeah i using jquery

Comment: @ Chetan Ranpariya  yeah i using jquery --- I got a one solution but it is not worked for the above json data . i have below posted that data and solution also.        var json = [{
    "name": "user1",
    "id": 3
}, {
    "name": "user2",
    "id": 6
}, {
    "name": "user3",
    "id": 1
}];
json.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.id - b.id;
});   i hoped u will understand the difference of the two json data.